# Redux toolkit watching state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have component which represent page, therefore it is parent Component.
I also have a second component which represents table, therefore it is child Component.
In parent component I skip api call, but I want watch data, because if there's no data, I don't want display filters, etc.

```
const Page = () => {
    const { isUninitialized, data } = useGetUsersQuery({ skip: true})

    if (!isUninitialized && !data.length) return <div>There's no data.</div>

    return <>
        <Filters />
        <Table />
    </>
}

const Table = () => {
    const { isLoading, isFetching, data } = useGetUsersQuery()

    if (isLoading || isFetching) return <div>Loading...</div>

    if (data) return <table>...</table>

    return null
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work.
I thought of using a useSelector hook.

```
const Page = () => {
    const { isUninitialized, data } = useSelector("???")

    if (!isUninitialized && !data?.length) return <div>There's no data.</div>

    return <>
        <Filters />
        <Table />
    </>
}
```

But it's not look much effective.
Till now I used combination of setState and useEffect.

```
const Page = () => {

    cont [ noData, setNoData ] = useState(false)
    if (noData) return <div>There's no data.</div>

    return <>
        <Filters />
        <Table setNoData={setNoData}/>
    </>
}

const Table = ({noData}) => {
    const { isUninitialized, isLoading, isFetching, data } = useGetUsersQuery()

    if (isLoading || isFetching) return <div>Loading...</div>

    useEffect(()=> {
        if (isUninitialized && !data.length) setNoData(true) 
    },[data])

    if (data) return <table>...</table>

    return null
}
```

However, I am not completely satisfied with any solution. Has someone a better idea?

Comment: I think first approach is not working because you are passing `skip` as an argument instead of a `useQuery` option. Use `const { isUninitialized, data } = useGetUsersQuery(undefined, { skip: true})`

Comment: @Rashomon I modified my real code, that's just example and there's no problem where you think.